# How can I find the number of primes between two numbers

Tags: prime-numbers

I'm not an advanced mathematician so I'm looking for some easy way . If there is no easy way . Then I'm doomed

Comment: Look up the prime counting function $\pi(x)$.

Comment: My students sometimes ask me for real-world applications of the math they study.  I'd *really* like to know how failure to count the number of primes between two numbers leads to being "doomed".

Comment: I was just kidding Eric Towers . I won't be doomed . I will be in this forum lurking around somewhere asking these kinds of questions.

Comment: The "easy" way is to ask [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=number+of+primes+between+123456+and+234567).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "easy formula for it". There are easy approximations for large values one of them being $\pi(x) \approx x/ln(x)$ where $\pi(x)$ is the prime counting function.

Therefore between $a$ and $b$ there are approximately $\frac{b}{ln(b)} - \frac{a}{ln(a)}$ primes and this approximation gets better the large the values are.

For an exact answer, you could use the Miessnel-Lehmer algorithm but it is more complex.

See here for the Miessnel-Lehmer Algorithm:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Lehmer_algorithm

Comment: Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are doomed or not depends on your definition of easy, and how approximate you can be. If there were a simple formula $p(x,y)$ for $x<y$ that gave you the number of primes between $x$ and $y$ integers, then by simply taking $\pi(y)=p(0,x)$ we would get a formula for computing precisely how many primes there are below a certain number. No such formula is know, thus there is no formula for the question you are asking. So, there is no easy way of precisely calculating the number of primes between to integers without testing the primality of every integer in between them. For small integers (say, below $1,000,000$), this is going to be "easy" for a not so powerful computer.

There are however approximations for the prime counting function given by $$\frac{x}{\ln{x}}<\pi(x)<\int_2^x\frac{1}{\ln(t)}dt$$ where both quantities converge to the exact value as $x$ becomes very large. Depending on how eactyou need to be, these approximations could be good enough (note that the integral converges much faster than the simple fraction, but depending on your tools available is not as easy to compute). To give an approximation for the number of primes between two integers ($x<y$) we would use the chosen approximatio for $\pi(x)$ and compute $\pi(y)-\pi(x)$.

For further information, see the wikipedia page on the prime counting function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function

Comment: "For small integers (say, below 1.000,000)" . Yup those a small numbers .